# How to access model or views attributes in django settings.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-settings

I want to update my Email Host user and password, which is present in my database .. i don't know how to update it. but i mentioned it in my settings.py file. like this,

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender_mail@mail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'passxxpass'....

 i want to change it dynamically while updating my database.
```

my table contain those email id and password. it may change dynamically based on user requirement. so i want do the same in `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `PASSWORD`... to send my mail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I Solved this by importing the below package in my view file,
   import django.conf as conf ... 
and using this i made the changes whatever i want dynamically like, for changing my EMAIL_HOST by using like this, 
  get_mail_data = mymodels.objects.get(head='Admin')
  conf.settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER = get_mail_data.from_mail

above is just an example what i used in my code... there from_mail is field present in my table.
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#send-mail) (which I presume you're using) has two parameters for `auth_user` and `auth_password`, you should use these instead of trying to change settings

`send_mass_mail` and others also have these parameters

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this. Settings are for things that don't change; if your email is dynamic, you should set that in the view when you send the mail.

Comment: i did that in view , but i cant setup mail user name and password from views.py... how to do that? i am using "EmailMultiAlternatives" to send html template along with my mail

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Also, you should not do this.

A better way to do this by creating a "Variable" table in your database.
Access the values from the table rather than settings file.